# Как узнать какие файлы добавились в папку

Tags: windows

Я скачал программу и при установке заметил что она устанавливает какие-то файлы в system32. Вот мне стало и интересно , что это за файлы. Вопрос: как узнать какие файлы были добавлены в папку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете список файлов "до", делаете список файлов "после", сравниваете. Еще можно взять procmon и смотреть им.

Comment: А если через ProcMon можно по подробнее?

Comment: @m1zl-s Задавайте конкретные вопросы, которые у вас возникнут после прочтения документации.

Answer (score 0):

Unistal Tool при установке может отслеживать все файлы, которые будут установлены. Журнал сохраняется.

Comment: А где найти этот журнал?

Comment: @0xdb программа "Unistal Tool"

Comment: @0xdb а на здоровье